# Using wsprintf to convert int to wchar_t*

Tags: c, wchar-t

I'm trying to get a `wchar_t*` formatted with an `int` as a parameter. I've Googled a lot but I've only ended up more confused. So, consider this code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   wchar_t buf[16];
   wsprintf(buf, L"%d", 5);
   wprintf(L"[%ls]\n", buf);

   system("pause");
   return 0;

};
```

Having assumed that `wchar_t`, `wsprintf` and `wprintf` are the wide character equivalents of `char`, `sprintf` and `printf` respectively, I expected the above to print `[5]`, but it prints garbage between `[` and `]`. What is the correct way to achieve the desired result? And what am I misunderstanding here?

(I should clarify that portability is more important than security here, so I'd like to know a solution that uses this family of functions instead of safer vendor-specific extensions.)

Comment: How do you know it's printing garbage? Have you piped the output into a file and looked at it in a hex editor?

Comment: No. I've assumed that `wprintf` would just print it to the console in the expected way. Is that incorrect somehow?

Comment: For me (Mac OS X 10.7.5), `wsprintf()` is unavailable, however `swprintf()` prints out `[5]` as expected.

Comment: Perhaps then you should change your question to "What is the correct assumption I should hold about this code?"

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you! It seems that I had misunderstood the naming convention for these functions. `wsprintf` is Windows specific, while `swprintf` is the actual wide character equivalent of `sprintf`. Would you care to make that comment an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Of course! I'll do it right now. Edit: done, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`wsprintf()` is a Windows-specific function, it's unavailable on Unixes. What you want to achieve can be done in a more portable way (I have tried this slightly modified code snippet and it worked as expected):

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    wchar_t buf[16];
    swprintf(buf, sizeof(buf) / sizeof(*buf), L"%d", 5);
    wprintf(L"[%ls]\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[5]
```

Answer (score 4):

`wsprintf()` is one of Microsoft's hybrid functions. It has a different signature depending on whether or not `_UNICODE` is defined during preprocessing. (What's happening under the hood, is there's an `#ifdef` that replaces `wsprintf` with `wsprintfA` or `wsprintfW` based on the nonexistence or existence of that symbol.)

If `_UNICODE` is defined, it expects the buffer to be of `wchar_t[]`.

If `_UNICODE` is not defined (usually the default), it expects the buffer to be `char[]`. That's what's happening here. If you had warnings on, it would probably show a warning about incompatible pointer types. The garbage is because the 8-bit ascii that it's storing in `buf` is being interpreted as Unicode by `wprintf()`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you're using an incorrect format specifier for your output. I would suspect you would want

```
wprintf(L"[%s]\n", buf);
```

%ls looks like an invalid combination of specifiers - l for a "long int" size prefix on the s "string" type specifier. Documentation I've found on wprintf indicates that it treats the 's' type specifier as pointing to a wide character string (at least for MS Visual Studio).

Comment: `%ls` and `%hs` are valid [MSVC format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx) for wide and "narrow" character strings. Using plain `%s` is a little more subtle.